# How to add conditional filter in query in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have this collection in my database and I want to filter documents following these conditions:

For documents filtered after the first stage I want to check if `custom === true` I want to add the filter:
`day === 'MONDAY'` and `startTime === 13:00`.

For documents with `custom === false`, I don't want to add the filter and I can return them in my query along with the documents that passed the custom filter.
Collection:
[image]

Code:

```
return await this.campaignModel.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          status: 'PENDING_START_DATE',
          startDate: { $lte: '2021-07-26' },
          endDate: { $gte: '2021-07-26' },          
        },
      },
     // add filter to documents that custom === true
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `$or` stage with different queries like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "$or": [
        {
          status: "PENDING_START_DATE",
          startDate: {
            $lte: 1
          },
          endDate: {
            $gte: 2
          },
          custom: true,
          day: "MONDAY",
          startTime: "13:00"
        },
        {
          status: "PENDING_START_DATE",
          startDate: {
            $lte: 1
          },
          endDate: {
            $gte: 2
          },
          custom: false
        }
      ]
    },
    
  }
])
```

With this query, if `custom:true` it will add values `day` and `startTime` into match, else, will not be added.

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ACw5E1HCFoW)

Comment: I edited the question and pasted the code for better understanding, can you help me?

Comment: Sorry I missunderstood the question. Check if query now works.

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo!